# C#.net How to ignore/eliminate date value from datetimepicker altogether?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm new here...

I'm using a bunch of DateTimePickers for a schedule form, but date is completely irrelevant. Only time is needed.

I've already edited the custom format to HH:mm and show the up/down arrows and everything. Removing the Calendar/date picker visually isn't the problem.

The problem is that there is still a date value stored in the back end. This is causing other problems in the rest of my code when I'm simply trying to compare timespans, as it will occasionally have a different date stored and miscalculate the total hours between times selected.

I've set the pickers to 00:00 by default and it seems to be picking today's date by default as well. I have some functions that change the picker values to certain times (by using DateTime.Parse("15:00") for example) and later found out that they are also changing the date value to the same date as the day I wrote that function (for instance, I use a message box to show me the value and it will say 12/7/18 when I call that same function).

Is there a way to make the whole thing ignore date altogether? Make it not exist anymore? Not store any date?

Or do I just need to set those DateTime.Parse things to use current date and whatever time?

---

edit: The answers didn't really help because I don't think I explained myself well enough for what I needed. I found a solution to the issue that prompted this question, though. I was setting default values for these pickers within Design view properties window, so the hidden date wasn't current. I just made a function to set them all to 00:00 with the current date when the form load by using DateTime.Parse("00:00"). This isn't quite the answer to my question but it fixed the problem I was having at least. I'm sure I'll understand these answers better when I have some more experience.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.timeofday

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1/

```
DateTime dt = /*...*/;
long ticks = dt.TimeOfDay.Ticks;
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(ticks);
```

But part of days can remain there (I am not fully sure about this).

2/ Another aproach is to write it in full constructor for DateTime:

```
TimeSpan ts = dt.TimeOfDay;
DateTime dt3 = new DateTime(0, 0, 0, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds);
```

Comment: Thank you. I think the first option is a bit outside my current understanding so I may just have to use the full constructor to set times instead of Parse. I'll have to do some more research first.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this:

```
date.TimeOfDay
```

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.timeofday?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_TimeOfDay

Comment: Hi, sorry, I'm not quite sure how to use that? I'm really extremely new to all of this and have zero formal training so I'm probably missing knowledge of basic principles and stuff here. Where would I be using this exactly? Right now I simply get a timespan by subtracting one datetimepicker.value from another and then i get the total hours of that timespan and compare it to some numbers in an if statement to do stuff. Sometimes I set the value programatically by using DateTime.Parse("12:00")  and then recalculate, and this is when it will store the wrong date occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

I've written this class recently for similar purposes, maybe it can be useful to you as a basis. You can modify the constructor to add parameters for example.

It uses TimeOfDay property as other answer mentioned, but via TimeSpan public property, it completely ignores the date and also can be databound.

```
public class TimeSpanPicker : DateTimePicker
{
    public TimeSpanPicker()
    { 
        Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
    }

    public TimeSpan Time
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Value.TimeOfDay;
        }
        set
        {
            this.Value = DateTime.Today.Add(value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
        OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Time");
    }
}
```